# Run php script from java application?

Tags: java, php

I have java client application and I need to run a PHP script on server. That PHP scrips will create some word and excel files and than I want to download that created files on client's machine.
Can I use somehow URL, but without opening a browser? And then download created files from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
      try {
        URL phpUrl = new URL("http://server/myphp.php");
        URLConnection urlCon = phpUrl.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                urlCon.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(line);
        br.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle errors here...
      }
    }
}
```

> you will need to modify the php applicatin to receive some details about the results.
>   Either the file location or maybe the file in MIME.

But you will need to add more information so we can help you out.

Comment: you could use the apache http client with lots of good features for calling urls and mgmnt [link]http://hc.apache.org/